# Problems in integrating Dropbox with android application

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am trying to  integrate Dropbox with android application using Dropbox API using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PjND_7Fzd8). My code compiles fine with no error. But when I try to download the file from Dropbox, I only receive an empty file. To me it seems that its not interacting with dropbox. Could you please have a look at my code. I am posting all my files. Thank you so much.

APP : My Application

MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static Button button1;
    public static Button button2;
    public static Button button3;
    public static Button button4;
    public static TextView textView;

    public static String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +  "/AAA_DB_Tutorials/"  ;
    public static File Dir =  new File(path);

    public void onClickBut1(View v)
    {
        UploadToDropboxFromPath(path + "testfile.txt", "db_tutorial/uploadFileFromPath.txt");

    }
    public void onClickBut2(View v)
    {
        UploadToDropboxFromSelectedApp("db_tutorial/UploadFilesFromSelectedApp");

    }
    public void onClickBut3(View v)
    {
        UploadToDropboxFromFilemanager(path + "testfile.txt");

    }
    public void onClickBut4(View v)
    {
        DownloadFromDropboxFromPath(path + "downloadFileFromDrobboxkkk","db_tutorial/uploadFileFromPath.txt" );

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        dropboxAPI = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        Dir.mkdir();


    }


    static DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropboxAPI;
    private static final String APP_KEY = "xxxxxx";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "xxxx";
    private static final String ACCESSTOKEN = "xxxxxx";
    private DropboxAPI.UploadRequest request;
    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession()
    {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        session.setOAuth2AccessToken(ACCESSTOKEN);
        return session;
    }
    static final int UploadFromSelectApp = 9501;
    static final int UploadFromFilemanager = 9502;
    public static String DropboxUploadPathFrom = "";
    public static String DropboxUploadName = "";
    public static String DropboxDownloadPathFrom = "";
    public static String DropboxDownloadPathTo = "";

    private void UploadToDropboxFromPath (String uploadPathFrom, String uploadPathTo)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final String uploadPathF = uploadPathFrom;
        final String uploadPathT = uploadPathTo;
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                File tmpFile = null;
                try
                {
                    tmpFile = new File(uploadPathF);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try
                {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                try
                {
                    dropboxAPI.putFileOverwrite(uploadPathT, fis, tmpFile.length(), null);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
                getMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }

    private void UploadToDropboxFromSelectedApp (String uploadName)
    {
        DropboxUploadName = uploadName;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Upload from ..."), UploadFromSelectApp);
    }

    private void UploadToDropboxFromFilemanager (String uploadName)
    {
        DropboxUploadName = uploadName;
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
        intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, UploadFromFilemanager);
    }

    private void DownloadFromDropboxFromPath (String downloadPathTo, String downloadPathFrom)
    {
        DropboxDownloadPathTo = downloadPathTo;
        DropboxDownloadPathFrom = downloadPathFrom;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        File file = new File(DropboxDownloadPathTo + DropboxDownloadPathFrom.substring(DropboxDownloadPathFrom.lastIndexOf('.')));
                        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            MainActivity.dropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxDownloadPathFrom, null, outputStream, null);
                            getMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                th.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == UploadFromFilemanager)
        {
            final Uri currFileURI = intent.getData();
            final String pathFrom = currFileURI.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    getMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            UploadToDropboxFromPath(pathFrom, "/db-test/" + DropboxUploadName + pathFrom.substring(pathFrom.lastIndexOf('.')));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
        if (requestCode == UploadFromSelectApp)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Uri uri = intent.getData();

            DropboxUploadPathFrom = getPath(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            if(DropboxUploadPathFrom == null) {
                DropboxUploadPathFrom = uri.getPath();
            }
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                        final File file = new File(DropboxUploadPathFrom);
                        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                        dropboxAPI.putFile("/db-test/" + DropboxUploadName + file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf("."),
                                file.getName().length()), inputStream, file.length(), null, new ProgressListener(){
                            @Override
                            public long progressInterval() {return 100;}
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(long arg0, long arg1){}
                        });
                        getMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    public String getPath(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
            if(s!=null) {
                cursor.close();
                return s;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        try {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
            if(s!=null) {
                cursor.close();
                return s;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        try {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return s;
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public MainActivity getMain()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tutorialspoint.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hellppppppo World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPLOAD WITH FIXED PATH"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClickBut1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPLOAD FROM SELECTED APP"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClickBut2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPLOAD FROM FILE MANAGER"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="onClickBut3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOWNLOAD"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClickBut4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tutorialspoint.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files ('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files ('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.tutorialspoint.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following? You didn't actually link to it.

Comment: Do you see the message "File successfully downloaded."? If not, do you see an exception in the log? The exception will probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @smarx Nope. It just shows "Download file ...". You were right. In logcat it shows "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/AAA_DB_Tutorials/downloadFileFromDrobboxkkk.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)". But I am sure that I have uploaded this file: C:\Users\user\Dropbox\db_tutorial\uploadFileFromPath.txt. and it has been sync on dropbox.

Comment: I have updated the link to tutorial. Pls see. @smarx

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code is failing before you actually try to download from Dropbox. That path looks like a local path, and your code is failing to open it. Maybe make sure that directory exists?